# Fixed points of the following linear transformation:

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-points

I have to find the fixed points of the following linear transformation:

$$T(z) = \frac{(-\frac 13 -i\frac 23)z - \frac i2}{\frac z2 -1}$$
where $z \in \Bbb C$.

I think I have to solve the equation $T(z) = z$.

By placing $z = x+iy$ I arrived at the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}3x^2-3y^2+2x+4y=0\\
6xy+2y-4x-3=0 \end{cases}$$

I'm not sure I did it right

Comment: It is easier if you solve $T(z)=z$ directly, the change of variable $z=x+iy$ complicates everything, since you have to solve a system of equations, which in this case is much more complicated.

Comment: So I have to solve it as if I were solving a simple first / second degree equation?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The only difficulty is that you will have to compute a square root of a complex number when you use the quadratic formula, but by far easier than solving this system of equations (which I don't have any idea how to solve it).

Comment: yes indeed it was a bit difficult system .. for this reason I thought I was wrong. This tip was very helpful thanks a lot